# How to search data relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I want when I do a search with the keyword name in Room to be successful, but I get an error if I also add a relation to Category, I want to fit my search looking for Category-> name and Room-> name, how is that? but but still error : Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Admin\RoomController::$category even though I have related room and category right

**This My Controller :**

```
$query = request('query');
        $room = Room::with(['category'])
                    ->where("name", "like", "%$query%")
                    ->orWhere($this->category->name, "like", "%$query%")->get();
        return view('admin.room.index', [
            'rooms' => $room
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `whereHas` to query a model based on its relationships:

```
$query = request('query');
$room = Room::with(['category'])
    ->where("name", "like", "%$query%")
    ->orWhereHas('category', function ($q) use ($query) {
          $q->where('name', "like", "%$query%");
    })->get();
    
     return view('admin.room.index', [
       'rooms' => $room
     ]);
```